# syn1neg & syn0 created as output

Tags: word2vec, gensim

as an output for creating a Word2Vec model on ~1GB of corpus I got 3 files as an output:

- word2vec_model
- word2vec_model.syn1neg.npy
- word2vec_model.wv.syn0.npy

I used to have only the first file on (when training a smaller corpus).

how should I treat the last 2 files when loading the model?
Should I load only the first one and run queries on it as usual?

Answer (score 0):

When internal arrays of a gensim model outgrow a certain threshold, they'll be `save()`d as separate files, for both efficiency and to avoid limitation of plain-`pickle()`ing.

You should keep these files alongside the main file – for example moving them along with the main file. But you only need to `load()` the main filename – the name you originally provided to `save()`. It will then find the subsidiary files automatically.